# Poor idle speed when engine is warm

Tags: mitsubishi, idle, throttle, stall

I drive a Mitsubishi Eclipse 2000 2.4L.

In the past few days my car has started to idle horribly when the engine warms up. While it is cold, the rpms seem to be normal except for a small fluctuation up and down. However, once the car warms up, it comes short of stalling when it's on neutral or the clutch is depressed. Also, when it's warm there is a delay in the throttle response. However, i have noticed that if I raise the Rpms to 6000 (close to the redline) the idle returns to normal until I start driving again. After I raise the rpms and the idle returns to normal, the throttle response is normal.

Any help would be appreciated 
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the throttle body?

Comment: No i haven't tried anything yet as i live in montreal and theres a bloody snowstorm outside!

Comment: Is the engine computer throwing any codes that you can read with a code reader?

Comment: No, I wrote all I could think of that might be of use. I'll try injector cleaner, hopefully it works!

Answer (score 1):

More then likely an idle air control valve thats failing, would replace and retest

Comment: Idle control valves usually get stuck and leave you revving higher than normal.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like dirty injectors or throttle body. Try running some injector cleaner (I like Techron, but there are many brands) through with your next tank of gas. I'd also recommend filling your car with the highest grade of gas you can get for a tank or two. The higher grades typically contain more fuel conditioners and detergents than the lower grades, and that can help to clean your fuel system too.

Comment: I tried injector cleaner, I'm not sure what happened though. Occasionally it works normally, but when I rev between 2000-4000 rpm the problem comes back.